# Copy Vs Mount a File system

Tags: linux, mount

I have one Linux login server and one VM I need to copy some files whenever i need to execute a test but it is a bottle neck to copy large number of files every time. instead of copy i am planning to use mount the filesystem from login server to VM. 
Question is : does copying from mounted folder is faster than copying from machine to machine ?

Comment: Should be the same. Copy is copy.

Comment: Are you interested in copying, or accessing the files?

Comment: Is the VM on the "login server" or on another machine? If it's a guest of the "login server" what virtualization is used : KVM? VirtualBox? How do you copy files? Would the amount of copy be reduced by using rsync?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. @ Melebius I am interested in accessing the files.